# How to append two XML documents in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need make two calls to a remote URL which returns XML as follows;

```
<results>
   <colours>
     <name>Red</name>
     <name>Green</name>
   </colours>
</results>
```

The 2nd response is like

```
<results>
   <colours>
     <name>White</name>
     <name>Blue</name>
   </colours>
</results>
```

The problem I have is I need to merge both responses into one XML document, and I really want just ONE results Root node.  How best can I do this ?  Because at the moment if I merge them together I get a error saying that I must have one Root Node

EDIT

I ideally I want the result to look like

```
<results>
   <colours>
     <name>Red</name>
     <name>Green</name>
   </colours>
   <colours>
     <name>White</name>
     <name>Blue</name>
   </colours>
</results>
```

Comment: So... you want two colours nodes?

Comment: See [Merging two xml files in C# without appending and without deleting anything (example given)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4045601/342740)

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel forgiven however next time refrain from using the words `from a developer standpoint` as it was your personal standpoint, best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
var doc1 = XDocument.Load(fileName1);
var doc2 = XDocument.Load(fileName2);

doc1.Root.Add(doc2.Root.Elements());
doc1.Save(fileName3);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to do this:

```
DataSet set1 = new DataSet();
DataSet set2 = new DataSet();
set1.ReadXml( new XmlTextReader( @"C:\File1.xml" ) );
set2.ReadXml( new XmltextReader( @"C:\File2.xml" ) );
set1.Merge( set2 );
set1.WriteXml( @"C:\File1WithFile2.xml" );
```